Can two different signal PCB tracks on the same layer(eg. MOSI crosses MISO) overlap or is this identical to connecting two wires together?
I'm working on my first PCB and it's fairly large and doesn't have much room. Any help is appreciated!

It's often a good idea when in doubt like that to ask oneself control questions. Like here - if it was the case that copper on circuit boards were different than wires - what is stopping you from crossing more traces? Why not all traces? The logical endpoint of that is just having one big copper plane with all signals "crossing", i.e. connected to it. If that was possible, why would we even bother with meticulouslt laying out PCBs?

They cannot overlap on the same layer. CAD programs should not even allow you to do this. Depending on the speed of the protocol and its specific requirements as well as the length of the interconnect (and the board material etc at higher frequencies), your options are:

Change your layout so they don't need to cross (preferred)
Move the traces to another layer where they don't need to cross (and/or increase the number of layers on your board)
Use jumper wires to go point-to-point, either for your signal if it can tolerate the multiple impedance discontinuities or another interfering trace that can


Tracks or other copper features on the same layer that touch or cross will be connected.
The PCB design program's Design Rule Check will report such connections as errors, if the program even allows you to draw the connection.
